# Get-ChildItem RuntimeException: Cannot index into null array

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to replace a line in several files and multiple folders with a PowerShell script:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.txt' | ForEach-Object {
    $content = Get-Content $_
    $content[7] = '    rel_nr    constant "{0}"' -f $releasenr
    $content | Set-Content -Path $_.FullName
}
```

The script works fine if the files are in the same folder as the script, but as soon as I try to implement

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\sample -Filter '*.txt' | ForEach-Object {
```

The script returns a RuntimeException:

```
Cannot index into a null array.
In C:\Users\mosermich\Desktop\Import-Daten-Uploader\Uploader.ps1:158 Char:9
+         $content[7] = '    rel_nr    constant "{0}"' -f $releasenr
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show the exact, unaltered error message. Does `C:\sample` contain .txt files? Do all of these files have at least 8 lines?

Comment: I've added the error message to the question. The folder does contain files and every one of them has atleast over 30 lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the

```
$content = Get-Content $_
```

with

```
$content = Get-Content $_.FullName
```

When you're running in a different location, `Get-Content` using only the `$_` will resolve to the filename and not the full path, hence it cannot find the file it's trying to fetch the content from. Using `FullName` will give it the full path instead. The reason why it worked when the files were in the same folder was because it would search from the working directory.

I would also consider safeguarding your statement to make sure it has more than 8 lines, just to avoid potential errors as for a good practice.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly. How can it be that $_.Fullname fixed the script? Did the loop not read the files correctly with just $_?

Comment: When you're running in a different location; Get-Content using only the $_ will resolve to the filename and not the fullname; hence it cannot find the file it's trying to fetch the content for. Therefore, using Fullname will give it the fullpath instead. The reason why it worked when the files were in the same folder was because it would search from the working directory.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution and explanation.